# How to use powershell scripting to delete registry files

Tags: powershell

I want to search and delete the all the registry files start with file name

For example, I want to install a software and then after I'm done with my work. I want to delete all the registry files that software contains, as if  that software was never installed using powershell.

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you searched Stack Overflow for similar questions?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: $path = "C:\Users\DFM\Desktop\shot 2 & 3.txt";
$func = 0;
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($path)) {
    if ($line -ne "" -and $line -notmatch "----------------------------------" -and